# Creating a non overlapping bins in R

Tags: r, bins

I have a set of x,y data (10,000). These data points are to be partitioned along the x-axis into non-overlapping bins of 10 data points each. From this, I need a new dataset, such that x = mean of these 10 data, y = maximum of these 10 data. The final data set should be 1000 sets of x,y. [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTV4m.png)

[Sample in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzjPL.png). I want to perform this task in R

Comment: Please provide some reproducible data and show some code what you have done already. Additionally you should rather ask one specific question instead of many.

Comment: Thanks, I can do it in excel, I have attached the sample in excel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What have you tried so far? Simply googling `r mean per group` and `r max per group` seems to give the answers you need.

Answer (score 1):

In tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  arrange(x) %>%
  group_by(grp = gl(n(), 10, n())) %>%
  summarise(x = mean(x), y = max(y))
```

In Base R

```
n <- nrow(df)
do.call(rbind.data.frame, by(df[order(df$x),], gl(n, 10, n),
     function(x) cbind(x = mean(x$x), y = max(x$y))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I created some sample data as you did not provide those.
I use the library `data.table` but you could do similar in `dplyr` or `base`.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
  x = sample(40:50, 50, replace = T),
  y = sample(1000:3000, 50)
)

dt[, grp := gl(.N, 10, .N)] # edit based on Onyambu's solution
dt[, .(x_avg = mean(x), y_max = max(y)), by = grp]

#    grp x_avg y_max
# 1:   1  44.7  2765
# 2:   2  45.3  2861
# 3:   3  44.7  2831
# 4:   4  46.2  2947
# 5:   5  46.7  2684
```

Comment: Thanks, if I have dataset of 54, and want to make one group of last remaining data, how should I change the code?

Comment: No need to change that, with the same code row 51-54 will be asigned group 6